# PHP accessing cookies from other domain with user explicit authorization

Tags: php, cookies, oauth

I'm coding a php framework to add functionalities for a second party website, which is not ours and don't have control at all.

This website has Oauth 2.0 authorization for its clients and save access token in cookies. As I must interact with their own public API, I need to read that token to make my requests.

Question is.. which is the best strategy to code that?  I'm not a php programmer but very proficient in C++. I wonder if its possible to open website inside an IFRAME and read cookies with javascript, am I making any sense????

Comment: You are making sense, but I think it's a bit of a security hole if that were possible. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, open the site in a hidden iframe, the page that the iframe loads should have something like

```
window.parent.getCookie(/* the cookie value*/);
```

So you can use the getCookie method is in your main site and read the external site cookie, then you can use ajax to send the cookie value to your script, and work with it or save it as a cookie, you can also use javascript to save the cookie.

EDIT: Remember cookies should never store sensitive data, even in your own site.

Comment: Sorry but is not working. Thanks for trying anyway. I think I'm gonna try to develop a browser plugin instead, there is one for Firefox that shows every cookie.

Comment: You can try making a service in the external site with the data you need, then in your site request that data